# Michel's cryptic kana

Tags: cipher, language

My friend [Michel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/31477/21402) is at it again. Today I found this email in my inbox:

> Subject: おいじゃくしゃあむう いみしゃあ りょん ぎをえしゃきょお
>
> てば おんない あきわんのんこお しいしゅう ぞびいけえ るう りゃいじい るう りょん わぐ えきゃ。お うてにょいつ うた ごりゅえや ごんをいれんや ううせえにょうさいじゃ なえ びわびきゃが おえないよお やきょお しゅがやえ きょざよん せ しいしゅう あいが。うにをえきゅう えにゅ おすう ああぬ るう ええこいにをいる るう お うてにょいつ。いいろお せ あえにょおま い あえこえ しいしゃあむう よだ ぴょ いきょお ぴゃ ううぴをいわひをいくう。しゅ えいねづう よだ ばいじゃ おいしをんひゃじょぎい せ えきゃ おえて いえきをぷう びわびきゃが あえねえ がいじゃ えんにゅ あんろんひゃ しゅ おえないよお ぎをねい い えいろんばじゅうなあ。じいかじゅう。

A quick check of [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#ja/en/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%84%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%8F%E3%81%97%E3%82%83%E3%81%82%E3%82%80%E3%81%86%20%E3%81%84%E3%81%BF%E3%81%97%E3%82%83%E3%81%82%20%E3%82%8A%E3%82%87%E3%82%93%20%E3%81%8E%E3%82%92%E3%81%88%E3%81%97%E3%82%83%E3%81%8D%E3%82%87%E3%81%8A) indicated he was either wishing me and my family a happy new year, or telling me that my nephew is a weak Amu cormorant. Anyway, I'm pretty sure he doesn't speak Japanese, so I'd guess he's using the kana to convey a hidden message.

I emailed back requesting a further sample, and got this:

> ぴいる おきゃぎゃえれんや うぴちょおや お おうじょこお げいるえぼきょい うた りわみほきゃ ちをぱあ なあ うた うれんや。お ああくんけえ じゃろお がいじい ええにをんひょぎい しゃあ りょん よぎゃ。ぴいる しゅう しゅ いぎえこお ぎいけえをじえ てやんくう。
>
> おえとん しいしゅう いじゅしょうや お ぎしょお べしゃあそきょい る しゅ ぽしい りょん こいむうべなあ るう お ううる ちをぱあ せ りょん えんじゃりえぎわぐ。お ううか しいる おんない ちみゃ じゃろお しゅ ううしゃあざ おんない ちみゃ りわじわえこお しゅ。お ちをきゅ ちゃきょん しいる しゅ しゅう ううりわじゅよん おえじょすかあ。しゅ おじをえしゅるくう りゃ しいないみい。しゅ しゅう あみょちゃきゅよん うた しいけじょん なえ げりゃ れえりょうちしをえ えいないきょいけえ おえて あみをゆんくう いをい うたが きゃる よすや びじわちをずうくう しゃあ うた ううこうやいごなあ なえ いいしゅう えぱあ ううさいちょん。しゅ しゅう ああぬ うえじわずしょうれい。お ぎいないよお よだ せ ううか いいしゃん おうわぶえこお ちをぱあ しゃあ い しいしをえちょうわぐう じじをえしわま なあ うた あいきょおけえめえないきょお いきょお いぎえこお せ もみゃ うた せえろおくう なえ いをい いいしゅう ぎゃをいのえせえるんけいやじゅう。お おえないよお えいろん い しいないぎきょお せ えきゃ いみしゃあぐ いいしゃん。
>
> おんない おえないよお をが ぴをにをえ あんなあこん てやんくう じゃりわじわえこお じやんよん。るう あえねえ うた いじゅしょうや お おえじをさ しゅ りょんがやえ。
>
> If that's not enough, I've got plenty more where that came from. ;)
>
> -M

What is the encryption method, and what do the messages say?

---

**Update:**

> **D:** Is a knowledge of the Japanese language needed to solve the puzzle?
> **M:** Grammar and vocab? No.
> **M:** Phonology and [spelling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana#Table_of_hiragana)? Maaaybe. ^_^

---

**Update 2:**

I asked Michel for another hint. He replied:

> Gosh, it's been years. Fortunately, I still have my notes--and the conversion program I wrote in Python.
>
> My main hint is to *start by breaking the ciphertext into syllables*. There are several caveats, because Japanese isn't as regular as I'd hoped:
>
> - Some syllables are written with one kana, some with more than one.
> - Don't rely on the pronunciation or the standard Romanization. For example, you've got to distinguish between じ and ぢ, even though they're both pronounced "ji." (Otherwise you might think my name was Mikhel instead of Michel.) Different underlying consonants, different syllables.
> - I used わ "wa" and を "wo" to plug the gaps in the table where "yi" and "ye" should have been. Unfortunately, they didn't have small versions for use in digraphs (like や "ya" versus ゃ "-ya"). So a word like ぎをねい "giwonei" is actually meant to represent "gi<sup>ye</sup>nei," which should be syllabified as "gye-nei." Clear as mud? I'm sure you can figure it out.
>
> I can't actually read any Japanese, so I apologize for giving a headache to anyone who can.
>
> - りょじいけい

Given what he said above about not depending on pronunciation and about the "yi" and "ye" substitutions, here's a modified version of the hiragana table:

|  | a | i | u | e | o |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **∅** | あ a | い i | う u | え e | お o |
| **k** | か ka | き ki | く ku | け ke | こ ko |
| **s** | さ sa | し si | す su | せ se | そ so |
| **t** | た ta | ち ti | つ tu | て te | と to |
| **n** | な na | に ni | ぬ nu | ね ne | の no |
| **h** | は ha | ひ hi | ふ hu | へ he | ほ ho |
| **m** | ま ma | み mi | む mu | め me | も mo |
| **y** | や ya | わ (yi) | ゆ yu | を (ye) | よ yo |
| **r** | ら ra | り ri | る ru | れ re | ろ ro |
| **g** | が ga | ぎ gi | ぐ gu | げ ge | ご go |
| **z** | ざ za | じ zi | ず zu | ぜ ze | ぞ zo |
| **d** | だ da | ぢ di | づ du | で de | ど do |
| **b** | ば ba | び bi | ぶ bu | べ be | ぼ bo |
| **p** | ぱ pa | ぴ pi | ぷ pu | ぺ pe | ぽ po |

Some other tips for syllabification:

- Consonant + y + vowel sequences are written with two hiragana by inserting an i and using a smaller version of the second character: kya -> ki-ya -> きゃ.
- Diphthongs and long vowels are written by adding a symbol from the ∅ row: sei -> se-i -> せい.
- There's a dedicated symbol to indicate a trailing -n: sen -> se-n -> せん.

Comment: I can communicate fluently in Japanese and can attest that this is gibberish... Reading pure kana without kanji gives me headaches...

Comment: what is kana, @stackreader?

Comment: @lois6b put simply, what is used here is hiragana(one of the 2 kinds of kana) which is 1 of the 3 alphabet japanese use. Usually it is mixed with kanji which is chinese symbols. Mixing kanji inside sentences is very useful to act as word delimiters. Pure kana like now makes it very hard to know when a word starts and ends... there is no spaces in Japanese.

Comment: @stackreader thanks for the info :D but the puzzle is solvable for non japanese speakers?? some kind of substitution works¿

Comment: @lois6b Probably solvable somehow but not a simple substitution. There is over 70 kana of which more than  40 are used here. so more than our alphabet.

Comment: @stackreader thanks again. I'll give it a try

Comment: counting spaces and the periods (because they exist in the cipher), there are 53 unique characters in the first part (subject included), and 62 in the second. Together, there are 67 characters used.

Comment: @Dlosc more hints may be beneficial...

Comment: @Stevo Hint added.

Comment: Thanks. I ought to have posted where I was at. I noticed most of those things already from looking at which kana appear next to other kana, but couldn't quite work out what WO and WA were doing. I can also see that A only follows five distinct kana, that U mainly follows kana with U and O sounds, that O only follows a small number of -O kana, which follows from the orthography for lengthened vowels. The only kana which appear twice in a row are the vowels and ZI (not DI). The most common Y-group is Syu, which is its own word and appears as both "Syu SyuU" and "SyuU Syu".

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer.
I highly suspect the kana have to be romanized before using some kind of substitution algorithm. And I wouldn't wish that infernal task on anyone who can't read Japanese, and I wouldn't trust most tools that could do it automatically either if such a tool exists. So here is the first part.

> oijakushaamuu imishaa ryon giwoeshakyoo
> teba onnai akiwannonkoo shiishuu zobiike ruu ryaiji ruu ryon wagu ekya.o utenyoitsu uta goryueya gonwoirenya uuseenyousaija nae biwabikyaga oenaiyoo yakyoo shugayae kyozayon se shiishuu aiga.uniwoekyuu enyu osuu aanu ruueekoiniwoiru ruu o utenyoitsu.iiroo se aenyooma i aekoe shiishaamuu yoda byo ikyoo bya uubiwoiwahiwoikuu.shu eineduu yoda baija aishiwonhyajogii se ekya oete iekiwobuu biwabiyaga aenee gaija ennyu anronhya shu oenaiyoo giwonei i eironbajuunaa.juukajuu.

I wrote it in like 1 minute so there might be 1 or 2 typos. But should be accurate.