# A bold and innovative gaming challenge

Tags: knowledge, video-games

[Michel's latest puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/48260/21402) has my brain in knots. I need to unwind. So I've settled on something fun to do with him, while also showing him he's not the only one who can craft tricky puzzles. Here's my email to him:

> Still puzzling over your Japanese challenge without making much progress, I'm afraid. While I'm working at it, I challenge you... to a game! Naturally, you'll have to figure out what the game *is* first. Email me once you find the answer.
>
> Q1:
>   - 52°14, 21°01
>   - 35°27, 43°15
>   - 45°25, 12°20
>   Q2:
>   - 38°42, 09°08
>   - 31°37, 08°00
>   Q3:
>   - 22°54, 43°11
>   Q4:
>   - 28°19, 31°25

What video game am I challenging Michel to play with me? **Please be as specific as possible.**

Comment: Can we get a hint?

Comment: @Gh0sT I made a small edit which may be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the hint we now know that

> The numbers are coordinates separated in 4 groups which I think refer to the 4 Earth quadrants going anticlockwise - NE, NW, SW, SE. The locations are:
>  - Warsaw, Poland.
>  - Ashur, Iraq.
>  - Venice, Italy.
>  - Lisbon, Portugal.
>  - Marrakesh, Morocco.
>  - Rio de Janeiro, Brazil.
>  - Ulundi, South Africa.
>  Some of them are capitals but some of them appear to be random places.

Well, not really!

> All of them are capitals of existing or historic countries:
>  Ashur - Assyrian Empire
>  Venice - Republic of Venice
>  Marrakesh - Saadi dynasty of Morocco
>  Rio - Kingdom of Brazil
>  Ulundi - Zululand

Now that we know that and also that we should be looking for a multiplayer game...

> All of them appear as civilizations in **Sid Meier's Civilization V: Brave New World**

Comment: Nicely spotted on the _Nyy bs gurz ner pncvgnyf bs rkvfgvat be uvfgbevp pbhagevrf._ (ROT13).

Answer (score 2):

**Very, very partial answer**

The locations appear to be

> Q1: Warsaw (N,E), Temple of Ashur on the Tigris river in Iraq (N,E), Venice (N,E). Q2: Lisbon (N,W), Marrakesh (N,W). Q3: Rio de Janeiro (S,W). Q4: Ulundi airport in South Africa (S,E). (I don't think there are "better" locations to be had by flipping N/S and/or E/W in any of these. I could of course be wrong. The second one in Q1 seems particularly unconvincing, but all its "partners" are in the middle of the ocean.)

So far all I've been able to turn up is that almost all of these are

> locations in the game *80 Days*. That seems extremely unspecific, though; *80 Days* is a geographical sort of game, and if the question had contained other major cities then they would most likely also have been game locations.

I am stupendously ignorant of video games, so further progress will probably have to be made by other people...